# How can find N unknown variable from less then N equation?.....

Tags: linear-algebra

We know if there is N unknown variable, we need N equation to find them.
Is there any equation that, how can find 3 unknown variable using less then 3 equation. Or How can find N unknown variable from less then N equation?

If a+b+c=x and a/x-b-x=y, we know x and y. then how can find a,b,c?

Comment: If you have $M$ equations in $N$ variables, where $M<N$, then you can choose freely $N-M$ variables.

Comment: Thanks for response. Is there any hint.

Comment: Hint to what?????

Comment: If a+b+c=x and a/x-b-x=y, we know x and y. then how can find a,b,c?

Comment: I'm weak in math, please help me.

Comment: That's a system of $2$ equations in $5$ variables, so choose $5-2$ variables freely, and calculate the remaining $2$ variables.

Comment: I've tried like this.. xy=a-b, x-c=a+b, a=(xy+x-c)/2 and b=a-xy. but can't solve c. is there any suggestion to solve c?

Comment: If I need to change those two equation and can solve 3 unknown variable, please suggest. But equations must be less then 3 means 2 or 1 equations.

Comment: Hello Mr. Barak, can you get any thing?